# Callback Delegate from C++/CLI Library causes InvalidOperationException in C# code - How to Invoke?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, c++-cli, invoke

I have written a Library in C++/CLI for easier access to MIDI functionality from managed code. The Library has a managed class which contains a class that offers a delegate as event handler and its called by the "native" Callback method of the midiInOpen function.

```
void MidiInDevice::MidiInProcNative(HMIDIIN midiInDevice, UINT msg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2)
{
    if(MidiInProcedure == nullptr)
        return;

    MidiMessage^ message;
    switch(msg)
    {
    case MIM_DATA:
        {
            message = gcnew MidiMessage(dwParam1, dwParam2);
            break;
        }
    }

    MidiInProcedure(this, message);
}
```

now I have added this method to the delegate, which is part of the C# application that loads the c++/cli library:

```
    public void MidiInProc(SharpMidi.MidiInDevice midiInDevice, SharpMidi.MidiMessage message)
    {
        tbMidiInMessages.AppendText(String.Format("\n{0}: {1:X}", message.TimestampString, message.Message));

    }
```

However I get an InvalidOperationException (Cross-Thread Operation Invalid) on the `AppendText` call.

When googling the issue, I got flooded with the obvious windows forms case of the exception, which somehow doesn't really help me as my MidiMessage class doesn't provide any Invoking functionality.

So what are my options to resolve this issue?

Regards,
Xaser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is completely related to Windows Forms.  Use the `Invoke` method of your `System.Windows.Forms.Textbox` object (`tbMidiInMessage`), or the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` that owns it (your `this` object in the C# UI code).

Comment: I totally facepalmed myself after I read your answer, due to some logic error or something I was convinced that the exception was caused by the read access to the MidiMessage Members... Thanks